# Source code for R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground

Tags: android, android-gallery

In Gallery view, there is a file used "`R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground`". Is there a way i can see the code of this file. I tried searching for the source code but didnt find it anywhere.

Hope you guys can help.

thanks!!

Comment: To point you in the right direction, the Android src [is mirrored on Github](https://github.com/android).

Comment: It might be possible to shell into your device, pull the `.apk` and decompile it. I think that's legal.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the Android source code file. It's in `res.drawable.gallery_item_background.xml`. You must make sure you can see the android source code first. I'm a Chinese so Enlish is not very well.

Answer (score 0):

The file that defines this styleable is found under **res/values/attrs.xml**